# Using DSolve to solve fourth order ODE

Tags: differential-equations

I am solving the following equation using Dsolve command in Mathematica:

```
DSolve[a1*y''[x] + y''''[x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

The general solution of these equations are of the form:

```
y = c1+c2*x+c3*Cos[Sqrt[a1]*x]+c4*Sin[Sqrt[a1]*x]
```

But, Mathematica gives me the following solution:

```
C[3] + x C[4] + (-((C[1] Cos[x Sqrt[a1]])) - (C[2] Sin[x Sqrt[a1]]))/a1
```

Although, both of the solutions are equivalent since you can always you can change your constants, however, I want the general solution (`y= c1+c2*x+c3*Cos[Sqrt[a1]*x]+c4*Sin[Sqrt[a1]*x]`) as the output from Mathematica. Can you please suggest what additional conditions I need to impose so that Mathematica gives result exactly as general solution?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: DSolve[a1*y''[x] + y''''[x] == 0, y[x], x]

Comment: Apply `Expand` to the output of `NDSolve`. Apart from naming conventions for the constants, the result is very close  to the desired form. You can replace the constants with `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: You mean `DSolve` and not `NDSolve` ?

Comment: Oops. Yes. I meant `DSolve`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use boundary conditions to fix the names of your parameters:

```
DSolve[{a1*y''[x] + y''''[x] == 0,
  y[0] == c1 + c3,
  y'[0] == c2 + Sqrt[a1] c4,
  y''[0] == -a1 c3,
  y'''[0] == -a1^(3/2) c4},
  y[x], x] // Expand
(* {{y[x] -> c1 + c2 x + c3 Cos[Sqrt[a1] x] + c4 Sin[Sqrt[a1] x]}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just combine constants.

```
DSolve[a1*y''[x] + y''''[x] == 0, y[x], x] // Flatten // Simplify

(*{y[x] -> (a1 C[4] x - C[2] Sin[Sqrt[a1] x] - C[1] Cos[Sqrt[a1] x] + a1 C[3])/a1}*)

y[x_] = y[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> -a1 C[1], C[2] -> -a1 C[2]} // Simplify

(*C[2] Sin[Sqrt[a1] x] + C[1] Cos[Sqrt[a1] x] + C[4] x + C[3]*)
```

Works because a1 * an arbitrary constant is still an arbitrary constant.